# Is PersistentComponentState tied to the SignalR circuit or global to the app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For Blazor render mode `InteractiveServer` Microsoft says the way to avoid reading in data twice for a page (pre-render and again post-render) is to [save it the first time using PersistentComponentState and then the second time just use the data saved off to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state).

Is this persisted data global to the app or is it scope level data tied to the session/circuit? Reading the docs it sounds like it's global, but it suggest as the key `nameof({VARIABLE})` and for multiple users hitting the same page, they would have the same key.

That will work if the data is per session/circuit. That will have key name conflicts if it is global.

And follow up question, if it's global, why not use MemoryCache? Which solves the re-read time hit not only for pre/post render, but for multiple people hitting the same page who should be shown the same data (like Events today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this and the `PersistentComponentState` is tied to the SignalR circuit (i.e. session) according to my tests. I'd prefer there was a categorical statement to that effect from Microsoft so I know we could depend on this going forward, but assuming I didn't screw up in my testing, it's tied to the circuit.

Also, remember that is is serializing to/from JSON and so if what you save is more than a couple of strings and/or numbers, there's a performance hit.